# CakePHP Twitter-clone: Can't get follow-system to work

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter

Sorry for the non-descript title, but I'm not sure how to phrase it.  Currently, I am trying my hand at developing a Twitter clone with cakePHP, since I'm new to web programming.  I have gone with 3 tables:

> users (id, name)

- id is the auto-generated id
- name of the user

> tweets (id, content, user_id)

- id is the auto-generated id
- content is the text of the tweet
- user_id is the id of the user that made the post

> followers (id, user_id, following_id)

- id is the auto-generated id
- user_id is the user who is doing the following
- following_id is the user that is being followed

Now, almost everything is basically working, even the follow function somewhat.  However, I think I may have set up the model relationships wrong.  In fact, I'm pretty sure it's wrong.

Right now, these are the model relationships:

- **User:** has many Tweets, has many Followers
- **Tweets:** belongs to User
- **Followers:** belongs to User

I'm pretty sure the Followers relationship is wrong, but that's what I've been working with.  Right now, what works is the user login/logout, sessions, posting, deleting your own posts, and following other uses (and then being able to see their tweets).

What doesnt work right now is when I try to get a list of people I'm following or people that is following me. The problem is I'm not sure how to access that data.

I want to have a screen where I can click on a link to see all the people I'm following and then see all of their latest tweets.

For example, I believe I can do a use a find() query to get a list of all the people I'm following, but as you can see from the Follower table above, that query only returns the user IDs of the follower and followee.  From that data, how do I get access to their names and latest tweet?

Do I do two lookups?  Is it something I can redefine in my model relationships, so that when in my ctp file, I can just php look through and use something like:

```
$this->$data['Tweet']['userID']
$this->$data['User']['name']
$this->$data['Tweet']['content']
```

I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I explained myself correctly...

I do hope my intention is clear however.  Any advice is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should use a [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) relationship with the followers, see also http://book.cakephp.org/view/1046/Multiple-relations-to-the-same-model for discussion on associating a model with itself.

Comment: I asked a friend of mine on his thoughts on this (as he is a web developer) and he said that I dont necessarily need to deal with the table relationships.  He said that in cake there should be some kind of way to access this data through one query, but I believe he just meant a simple find query on both data sets.  Unless there's something Im missing here, I somehow think that the way you are proposing makes more sense...

Comment: Yeah, unless I completely misunderstood the question, if you make the HABTM relationship you can get everything you need with one query.

Comment: I dont think you misunderstood the question.  However, perhaps I need to clarify something.  If I made a HABTM relationship with the followers, wouldnt I then have 4 tables?

Users (id, name), Tweets (id, content, user_id), Followers (id), Users_Followers (user_id, following_id)?  

Perhaps this is where I need to reread the relations to the same model link you suggested as this doesnt look right to me somehow..:)

Comment: No, you don't need the followers table because the users table would be associated with itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app/models/user.php

class User extends AppModel{
      var $name = 'User';

      var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Follower' => array(
                  'className'             => 'Follower',
                  'joinTable'             => 'user_users',
                  'foreignKey'            => 'user_id',
                  'associationForeignKey' => 'child_user_id'
            )
      )
}

app/models/follower.php

class Follower extends AppModel{
      var $name     = 'Follower';
      var $useTable = 'users';
}
```

You will have to make a table user_users with the fields user_id and child_user_id. child_user_id would be the follower ID, you could name it follower id if you want but it might be confusing if you need to make a similar relation in the future.

Try it out.

Comment: I don't think he needs a new table, his `followers` table *is* the join table (it should join two different instances of the User model).

Comment: Yes, but he should get rid of that followers table and make a user_users one. It makes more sense if you want to do the same relation in the future. For example with subscribers or friends, it would get completely confusing if he puts it in followers, and even worse if he makes a new table for it.

Comment: Thank you!  But does this mean that I don't need a model for the user_users table?

Comment: Your followers model is the user_users model, because it uses that table.

Comment: Thank you, but even with this new way, I'm not sure what my find() query should look like.  For example, I suppose I'd want to run a query along the lines of "select all the users that are being followed by user_id = 1".  However, wouldn't I need to query two tables, one after the other?  First query will be on the Follower table to find all the IDs, then a second query to run through the Users to find the related info like name.

Is there some way to run a single query on the users table to get all the people (along with their user names, etc)  a particular ID is following?

Comment: Hello, I worked on this over the weekend, and have gotten it to work using that above link (thank you!).

I used the following statement:   $this->User->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('UserUsers')));  
  $data = $this->User->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array('User.*'),
      'conditions'=>array(
    'UserUsers.child_user_id'=> $current_id)));

However, I realized that I needed to get a list such as: "find all the users that the (logged-in) user is following and show each of their latest tweets.  So I tried this:

Comment: $this->User->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('UserUsers')));  
  $fields = array('User.*');
  $condition = array(
   'UserUsers.child_user_id'=> $current_id);
  $contain = array(
    'Tweet' => array(
       'order' => 'Tweet.date DESC',
          'limit' => 1));

  $data = $this->User->find('all', compact('condition', 'contain'));

However, with the contain behavior in the model and this contain in the find, the conditions are now being ignored.  While the tweets are limited to the latest per user, it is listing every user (and not just the ones being followed)

Comment: Sorry, it seems it's because I used "condition" and not "conditions"

However, now I am getting this error: SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'UserUsers.child_user_id' in 'where clause'

Does using the contain behavior break this bind behavior, as it seems to have done to my query?