# CakePHP returning the wrong column in a find query in a HABTM relationship

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, find

I've been wrestling with this find() query for a while.  For reference about the tables, see the question here: [CakePHP Twitter-clone: Can't get follow-system to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671525/cakephp-twitter-clone-cant-get-follow-system-to-work).

However, in short, this is for a twitter clone I'm doing for self-learning.  I have three tables.

```
Users (id, name)
Tweets (id, user_id, content, date)
UserUsers (id, user_id, follower_user_id)
```

As models, I have Users, Tweets, and Followers (HABTM users).

Right now, I have this find query:

```
$this->User->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('UserUsers')));  
        $fields = array('User.username');
        $conditions = array(
            'UserUsers.user_id'=> $current_id);
        $contain = $this->User->contain(array(
            'UserUsers',
            'Tweet' => array(
                'fields'=> array('Tweet.content', 'Tweet.date'),
                'order' => 'Tweet.date DESC',
                'limit' => 1)));

        $data = $this->User->find('all', compact('fields', 'conditions', 'contain'));
```

Which produces this SQL statement, which is ALMOST what I want:

```
SELECT `User`.`username`, `User`.`id` FROM `users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `user_users` AS `UserUsers` ON (`UserUsers`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `UserUsers`.`user_id` = 1
```

This is very close, but it's returning the wrong column in my table.  I would like to produce the follow SQL statement:

```
SELECT `User`.`username`, `User`.`id` FROM `users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `user_users` AS `UserUsers` ON (`UserUsers`.`follower_user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `UserUsers`.`user_id` = 1
```

Any help on how to tweak my find() query would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `'associationForeignKey' => 'follower_user_id'` in your User model?

Comment: Yes, my user model has this:

 var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
          'Follower' => array(
                'className'             => 'Follower',
                'joinTable'             => 'user_users',
                'foreignKey'            => 'user_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'follower_user_id'
          )
    );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment explains it all :D 
You said that you have something like this:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
   'Follower' => array( 
       'className' => 'Follower',
       'joinTable' => 'user_users',
       'foreignKey' => 'user_id', 
       'associationForeignKey' => 'follower_user_id'
));
```

With this you are telling cake to join the user model table with user_users by user.id = user_id  (look at the foreign key) using your conditions like `UserUsers`.`user_id` = 1 THEN it will join user_users table with Follower model table using Follower.id = follower_user_id

Cake won't do a sql query with joins for HABTM or hasMany, so what you post is just the first part, you should take a look for the second part. So what you are getting IS the normal behaviour for this find and there is nothing wrong with it, check your sql dump for the other part and you will see what i mean :D

You can do [force join manually](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables), or try doing a behaviour like [linkable](https://github.com/Terr/linkable)

Hope this solves your question

Comment: thank you!  I used a manual join on the tables, which worked! :)